# VSCode definition stays forever

Tags: visual-studio-code

Something annoyed me for long times. Tried to find a solution but couldn't get any.

On my vs code, when I called a method vscode shows method definition, which is really good. I like that feature. But the tooltip / popover or whatever it's called stays like forever until I click somewhere else with my mouse which is very very annoying. Is there any way to **disable** this? God helps me.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the setting. For those, who are looking the answer, add the line below on vs code `settings.json` file.

```json
"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false
```